# If a person is hit by an object, are their bones under predominantly compressive or shear stress?

Tags: forces

Say a person is standing still and they get hit by a tennis ball, are their bones under compressive or shear stress due to this impact? In actuality, I know they're under both, but the specifics of what each kind of stress actually is has me confused.

Shear stress is described by wikipedia as force coming from a vector parallel to the materials cross section. However, can't you draw a cross section from any angle, so you could have a bone cross section that looks like a distorted circle if it is drawn viewed from the "top", or one that looks like the silhouette of the bone if it's drawn from the "side".

Answer (score 0):

Generally bones are under compressive stress and are optimized for this. The HUman body is an example of [Tensegrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensegrity)

> Tensegrity, tensional integrity or floating compression, is a
> structural principle based on the use of isolated components in
> compression inside a net of continuous tension, in such a way that the
> compressed members (usually bars or struts) do not touch each other
> and the prestressed tensioned members (usually cables or tendons)
> delineate the system spatially.
>
> ...
>
> Biotensegrity, a term coined by Dr. Stephen Levin, is the application
> of tensegrity principles to biologic structures.[6] Biological
> structures such as muscles, bones, fascia, ligaments and tendons, or
> rigid and elastic cell membranes, are made strong by the unison of
> tensioned and compressed parts. The muscular-skeletal system is a
> synergy of muscle and bone. The muscles and connective tissues provide
> continuous pull[7] and the bones present the discontinuous
> compression.

Comment: I'd figured as much, with the leg and spine bones being under a lot of compressive stress and the arms being under 1 g of tensile stress. I'm pretty sure I understand what each stress type is intuitively, but when dealing with physics I'd rather not trust my gut blindly.